# Tuning resonnator in open g

Tags: acoustic-guitar, tuning

I have been playing guitar for a couple of years and recently acquire a metal Dobro for slide. I have put new strings on it and I'm a bit worry about the tuning. The strings are quite heavier gauge than my other guitars and I'm just wondering about the tuning. I use an chromatic tuner and stop as soon as the strings hit the first octave, but it seems a bit floppy. However if i try tuning an octave higher i'm afraid to break the neck because of the tension. Anyone can help?

Comment: Check this out. May help. https://artistworks.com/blog/dobro-tuning-andy-hall

Answer (score 1):

The strings will break **long** before the neck breaks. Aside from that, you should know or be able to find the correct pitches, including the correct octave, for each string. There are resources online that will tell you the tension that a string of a given gauge will be under when tuned to a given note. You can add up all the tensions and check with the guitar manufacturer to make sure everything will be ok.